Translate SUMIF from Excel to SQL
I need to extract in Excel invoices from AS400 table but there are just values from each line is not the total amount of the invoice. Now I have query to extract each line of the invoices to Excel and I make the total with formula SUMIF(I:I,"="&I1,Z:Z). Column I contains invoice number and Z value of each line from invoice. I want to calculate the sum directly in the query to eliminate Excel formulas.
Thank you
I tried this but I receive message, keyword FROM not expected. I don't see what is missing.
SELECT 
    LPLI.LGRGNR AS invoice_number,
    LPLI.LGTENR as product_name,
    LPLI.LGNEWT as product_value,
    SUM (LPLI.LGNEWT FROM X800SD.LPLI LPLI) OVER (PARTITION BY LPLI.LGRGNR ORDER BY LPLI.LGRGNR) AS total_invoice_value
FROM 
    X800SD.LPLI LPLI
GROUP BY 
    LPLI.LGRGNR, LPLI.LGTENR, LPLI.LGNEWT
ORDER BY 
    LPLI.LGRGNR, LPLI.LGTENR, LPLI.LGNEWT


If you look at Shahed Mahmoudi answer again I think it is OK and I think you are missing a comma.
If I do this example ,
select table_name,column_name,data_type,length,numeric_scale 
count(column_name) OVER(PARTITION BY table_name) AS "total columns in table"
from qsys2.syscolumns 
where table_schema='VEHTST';

I get the same error you got,

Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO. Cause...

If I do this instead it works,
select table_name,column_name,data_type,length,numeric_scale ,
count(column_name) OVER(PARTITION BY table_name) AS "total columns in table"
from qsys2.syscolumns 
where table_schema='VEHTST';

See comma added after numeric_scale

I have formatted the code in the answer for you. We do this by marking the code and then pressing the code format button {}.

I suppose your answer is for other question. I have the same error, but I have comma there, where you said. Before SUM, in my case.

user2073499 hope you are sorted now with @Shahed Mahmoudi solution

With or without comma before SUM, the message is the same. Still not ok.
